# Matlab: How to calculate the number of seconds between two date strings?

Tags: matlab

I have two dates in the following format:

```
'16:40:07.875'

'16:41:05.875'
```

Now I try to use Matlab to calculate the difference between these two date strings in seconds. I thought the best approach is to first parse the date strings into a date type, but I couldn't find any date type in Matlab. Is there any? And is there a pre-built function that I could then use to calculate the difference?

Comment: have you tried [`etime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/etime.html)?

Comment: Yes, but for that I need first a date vector and I don't know how to get a date vector from my strings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
T1 = '16:40:07.875';
T2 = '16:41:05.875';

T3 = clock;

str1 = [num2str(T3(1:3)),' ',T1];
str2 = [num2str(T3(1:3)),' ',T2];

t1 = datevec(str1,'yyyy mm dd HH:MM:SS.FFF')
t2 = datevec(str2,'yyyy mm dd HH:MM:SS.FFF')

Dt = etime(t2,t1);
```

In this case `Dt` is `58`.

Some explanations:

- First, I use [`clock`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clock.html) to get todays day-string to serve as a dummy for the year/month/day input
- Second, I use [`datevec`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datevec.html) to get the right date-vector format. Notice the `SS.FFF` to resolve the milliseconds.
- Third, [`etime`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/etime.html) is applied to compute the delta between the two date vectors.

**Edit**
As [Oleg Komarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2180721/oleg-komarov) pointed out, this will be sufficient:

```
t1 = datevec(T1,'HH:MM:SS.FFF')
t2 = datevec(T2,'HH:MM:SS.FFF')

Dt = etime(t2,t1);
```

Comment: You actually do not need the `clock()`, `datevec()` takes care of it.

Comment: @Schorsch you just saved my day man. Thanks for this FFF thing. The normal datevec does not show this part - do you have any idea why? cheers man

Comment: I had timestamps with milisecond resolution and in the matlab webpage of the datevec function I didn't see this option with the miliseconds (FFF)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my not-so-clever and rather long attempt using [datenum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html?searchHighlight=datenum) and [datetime](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html?searchHighlight=datetime). 
I am merely providing solution to mention some of the other time/date API.

I'm using [diff](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to return the difference as a [duration](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/duration.html). Then I need to convert from HH:MM:SS duration to seconds only duration. Finally I split the string and return the first token.

```
T1 = '16:40:07.875';
T2 = '16:41:05.875';
dt1 = datetime(datenum(T1,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'),'ConvertFrom','datenum');
dt2 = datetime(datenum(T2,'HH:MM:SS.FFF'),'ConvertFrom','datenum');
timestamps = [dt1 dt2];
seconds_text = char(duration(diff(timestamps),'Format','s'));
items =strsplit(seconds_text);
Dt = str2num(items{1,1});
```